# Accidentally deleted /etc/resolv.conf and now can't access any domain

Tags: 18.04, dns, resolv.conf, resolvconf

I was getting dns probe finished message in chrome on Ubuntu 18.04 so I looked up on the internet and tried to run the following commands.

```
sudo rm/etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /var/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Above 2 commands executed successfully but the following didn't.

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

It gives an error message that `resolvconf` is not installed.

Now, nothing is working and `/etc/resolv.conf` file is empty. I'm not even able to edit it (I tried to a add `nameserver 8.8.8.8`).

Please help.

Edit: i'm still getting ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVE and here's the output of 'service --status-all`.

```
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ - ]  alsa-utils
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  apport
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  cups-browsed
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ - ]  dns-clean
 [ + ]  gdm3
 [ + ]  grub-common
 [ - ]  hwclock.sh
 [ + ]  irqbalance
 [ + ]  kerneloops
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ + ]  network-manager
 [ + ]  networking
 [ - ]  plymouth
 [ - ]  plymouth-log
 [ - ]  pppd-dns
 [ + ]  procps
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ - ]  saned
 [ + ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ - ]  spice-vdagent
 [ + ]  udev
 [ + ]  ufw
 [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  uuidd
 [ + ]  whoopsie
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

Comment: On 18.04 `/etc/resolv.conf` points to `../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fix this you should recreate the link how it was. On 18.04 `/etc/resolv.conf` points to `../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`.

So to fix your problem it should be enough to do the following:

```
sudo rm resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: In my native 18.04 I have `/etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`, in my VirtualBox 18.04 I have the link like you wrote. My native 18.04 is an upgrade from 17.10 but the VB system was a fresh install - perhaps this explains the difference?

Comment: Probably. This 18.04 I have here was a total fresh install, so I guess too that your different linkage is due to being an upgraded system.

Comment: @Videonauth Thanks. But I'm still occasionally getting ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. What should I do? I googled and found this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029603/no-internet-connection-after-update-17-04-to-18-04 

The output of `sudo service --status-all` is added in question.

Comment: Did you restart the machine after the repair?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I continue to get the same message of DNS BAD CONFIG

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and just removed the `resolv.conf` file by using the same commands!
here is how I fixed it:
if you are using gnome, then: 
`sudo service network-manager restart`
this will recreate all the necessary files automatically.