# accidentally modified /etc/resolv.conf and now cannot acces the Internet

Tags: networking, systemd, resolv.conf

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 on my dell inspiron 5402.I was annoyed about frequently getting a question mark on that wifi icon,so I followed some method on the Internet and unfortunately got this problem.

Now when I open chrome, there is **DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD__CONFIG** displayed.
I checked my `/etc/resolv.conf` file and it showed  `broken symbolic link to /run/systemd/resolv/stub.resolv.conf`,but when I checked the `/run/systemd/` directory ,there was no `resolv`.
I viewed this related answer  [Accidentally deleted /etc/resolv.conf and now can't access any domain](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040812/accidentally-deleted-etc-resolv-conf-and-now-cant-access-any-domain) but it doesn't fit my situation.

I get fully confused and don't know what to do next .

[image]

Comment: `ls -al /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` please add this to your question.

Comment: sorry, because the ubuntu cannot access the network , i have no way to add those on .  Those are just names of wifi I previously used

Comment: `sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf`  and `sudo ln -s /run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf
/etc/resolv.conf`  and restart all NetworkManager services.  `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service NetworkManager-wait-online.service` then try to connect over gui.

Comment: I followed your advice,but the situation stil remains the same

Comment: Any errors?  Is `ls  -al /run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf` on your system present?

Comment: no errors detected during those instructions,but the result is still the same . I add the result of ```ls -al /run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf``` in the question

Comment: last try from me. Make a reboot erase your old connections in `network-manager-gnome` and create your connection new.

Comment: `/etc/resolv.conf` usually links to either `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` or `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`.  Do these files exit on your system?

Comment: What, specifically, did you do to cause the problem? "some method" is insufficient information.